# Javascript not showing up in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am making my web app on localhost, but the browser page keeps showing up as blank, what am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

window.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
W = window.innerWidth,
H = window.innerHeight;


setInterval(draw, 33);

function draw() {
ctx.globalcompositeOperation = "source-over";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,W,H);
}
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for error messages?

Comment: Corrected that but still the same problem

Comment: @Hacketo — The end tag for the body element is (according to the HTML specification) optional (as is the start tag).

Answer (score 5):

You declare a bunch of variables inside the anonymous function you assign to `onload`. They are not globals.

You then try to (on an interval) access them as globals.

If you look at the Console in your developer tools you should expect to see a bunch of *ReferenceErrors*.

Move `setInterval` and the `draw` function declaration *inside* the anonymous function you assign to `onload`.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        W = window.innerWidth,
        H = window.innerHeight;


    setInterval(draw, 33);

    function draw() {
        ctx.globalcompositeOperation = "source-over";
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
    }
}
```

```html
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I corrected it like you said but still the same problem

Comment: @zigg75483 — It works fine in the demo in the answer.

Comment: Yeah so I am not sure why mine doesn't show up, I even copy and pasted your code but still just blank for me

Answer (score 1):

Just a few issues with variable scope, among other things mentioned by @Quentin.  You were defining local variables `ctx`, `W`, and `H` inside `window.onload`, which isn't accessible from `draw`.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    var ctx, W, H;

    window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      W = window.innerWidth;
      H = window.innerHeight;
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      setInterval(draw, 33);
    }

    function draw() {
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

For future reference, it's also a good idea to move scripts to the end of the `body`, so you don't have to add events for the window load or `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: I copied your code but it is still blank for me, not sure what is going on

Comment: Then I'm *really* not sure what you've done, you can run the snippet here and see it working.

Comment: I have managed to get the black background to appear, but it doesn't show up as the full page, even though window.innerwidth is used

Comment: That's because the actual canvas isn't the size of the window.  Try setting `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` to `W` and `H`, respectively in `window.onload`.