# Javascript no shapes appear

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to just make a rectangle but nothing will appear, just the background. I've tried ctx.fill, ctx.fillStyle etc. nothing works:

I'm refering to this part

```
fill(77, 66, 66);
rect(10,200,100,100);
```

Here is the whole code for the page

```
 var ctx, W, H;




window.onload = function() {


  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  W = window.innerWidth;
  H = window.innerHeight;

  canvas.width = W;
  canvas.height = H;


  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


  setInterval(draw, 1);


function draw() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#E6E6FF"; // this part does appear
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

  fill(77, 66, 66); // this doesn't appear
  rect(10,200,100,100);

}


}
```

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't it be ctx.fill and ctx.rect?

Comment: I have tried those too (see start of post)

Comment: I think you should [step back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784673/javascript-not-showing-up-in-browser/32784727#32784727) and read through a [canvas tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/), @zigg75483

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **fill** and **rect** on the canvas context.
Also you need to change the **fillStyle** otherwise you're drawing a rectangle with the same color as the background and it won't show.

```js
var ctx, W, H;



window.onload = function() {


  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  W = window.innerWidth;
  H = window.innerHeight;

  canvas.width = W;
  canvas.height = H;


  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


  setTimeout(draw, 1);


  function draw() {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#E6E6FF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

    ctx.fillStyle = "red"; // need this otherwise the rect will be the same color as the background
    ctx.rect(10, 200, 100, 100); // needs to be called on the canvas context
    ctx.fill(); // needs to be called on the canvas context, it will fill any path not already filled in.
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are filling both areas with the same color, and you have to use the context to perform fill functions. you also need to create the rect BEFORE you fill it.

Try this on for size: https://jsfiddle.net/szbk6f67/3/

```
var ctx, W, H;

window.onload = function () {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    W = 400;
    H = 400;

    canvas.width = W;
    canvas.height = H;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    setInterval(draw, 1);

    function draw() {
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'gray';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.rect(10, 200, 100, 100);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```